# how to calculate time spent on my app by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

i have one column timestamp when user enters the app and another column when user leaves the app . i want to calculate the time spent on the app : 
sum(timestamp_exit) - sum (timestamp_enter) .

right now i've tried to right the current query :

```
select (SUM(unix_timestamp(`created_time_enter`))) as enter , (SUM(unix_timestamp(`created_time_exit`))) as exit
FROM `my_table`
```

but i get large numbers and i don't know if it's the correct way. any suggestion?

Comment: The query above seems legit but if you have any way to discriminate users, be sure to use GROUP BY {insert user_id column here} to make sure results will be distinct according to their user. When you're saying that you obtain large number, remember that you have to convert those numbers (which is a timestamp) to the time unit you need

Comment: Legit? Are you sure?

Comment: If something starts at 103 (seconds) and ends at 105 seconds, does it take 208 seconds?

Comment: how to convert ? and doesn't the unix_timestamp return in seconds ?!

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate this using the timeDiff function:

```
times = array();

foreach ($result as $row){
    // convert to unix timestamps
    $firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
    $lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

    // perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
    $timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;
    $times[] = $timeDiff;
    echo(secondsToTime($timeDiff));
    # 18 days, 23 hours, 41 minutes and 7 seconds
}

echo(secondsToTime(array_sum($times)));
#total of all times
```

Comment: you mean foreach row in select of the timestamp for enter and for exit i should do this ? where the sum of all the exit and sum of all the entries ?