# How to calculate time of an third party app currently open in my app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app which will calculate the amount of time a third party app is used and after closing that it will pop up and display the amount of time the app was on. We can find the the same thing for our app usage by timestamp as described here: [how to calculate time spent on my app by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321654/how-to-calculate-time-spent-on-my-app-by-timestamp)
**How can I calculate the (on/activated)time of third party app?**

Comment: You need to be careful with `onPause` and `onResume` because the user might minimize the app and then come back to it. How do you start the third part app from your app?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you call a third party app from an activity so you could either calculate the delay starting when the app is called for result and ending when onActivityResult is called.

You could also start the timer when onPause is called and end it when onResume is called, because your activity loses focus when another starts.

EDIT

If your app is not launching other apps, then you can use a service with the READ_LOGS permission and detect the ActivityManager logs to see which intents were called, something like

```
I/ActivityManager(  585): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action,..}
```

Search for the ActivityManager tag.

Comment: Hello, I want my app to collect information in background and when the third party app is closed it will pop up. I mean When you are launching/using any app on your phone my app should start calculating the time in background and when the activity is ended it should then open up like a pop up. I don't want to start the third party app from my app.